# How to use 者 as "... one who is ..."?

Tags: translation

I have read that 者 can be used as "... one who ...", for example

*I met a X, one who is a Y.*

Is that right? If yes, what would be the translation of "I met a X, one who is a Y"?

Answer (score 2):

> [者](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&char=%E8%80%85)
>
> 英文翻譯: that which; he who; those who
>
> 《禮記·檀弓上》
>   遂命子貢為之主，曰：「為爾哭也來者，拜之。」
>
> Accordingly he ordered Zi-gong to act as presiding mourner on the occasion, saying to him, 'Bow to **those who** come because you have a wailing in your house.'

之 in 拜之 is a pronoun which represents 來者.

I think it is usually used in the classical Chinese (文言文).

Answer (score 2):

> [者](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/591/):
>
> the person/people who; he who; those who; that which
>
> *者 is the literary counterpart of the colloquial "的人" or "的" (pronoun)*

The usage of "者" compare to English "he who" , "those who"

- English: [**pronoun**] + [**who** (used to introduce a clause giving further information about a person or people previously mentioned.)] + [*descriptive clause*]
- Chinese: [*descriptive clause*] + [**者** pronoun] (used to indicate the clause before it is a description of the pronoun '者')

Example:

- English: [**those**] + [**who**] + [borrowed money from Mr.K (*descriptive clause)*]
- Literary Chinese: [向 Mr.K借钱 (*descriptive clause*)] + [**者**]
- Colloquial Chinese: [向 Mr.K借钱 (*descriptive clause*)] + [**的人**]

> 者 is also a common component that turn nouns or verbs into compound word nouns

Examples:

作 = create; 作者 = author

記 = to record; 記者 = reporter

死 = dead; 死者 = the deceased

學 = to learn; 學者 = scholar

弱 = weak; 弱者 = weakling

侍 = to serve; 侍者 = waiter

讀 = read; 讀者 = reader

Answer (score 2):

That is classical Chinese.

Some examples:

**师者, 传道授业解惑也---韩愈**. 
This is a famous quote, frequently used when people talk about teachers and students.

Translation:

A teacher, [is a person] who passes down the
Dao, imparts professional knowledge and resolves doubt.

I found that translation in this [doc](https://www.academia.edu/35903850/A_Translation_of_the_Shi_Shuo_Discourse_on_Teacher_by_Hanyu_%E9%9F%A9%E6%84%88_%E5%B8%88%E8%AF%B4_%E4%B9%8B%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%91):

Similar usage:

窃谓夫为将**者**：能去能就，能柔能刚；能进能退，能弱能强。 -- 诸葛亮

为将**者**不通天文、不懂地理、不晓阴阳、不知奇门遁甲及阵图兵势，乃庸才也 -- 诸葛亮

凡为将**者**，知过于人，则能制人。--锺繇

Sometimes people want to use it intentionally to make the sentence sounds special.

楼主者, 发贴首也.

OP is the person who post the first message in a threads.

为球员者, 当以团队第一.

The one who as football player should treat the team first.

Comment: In 「师者，传道授业解惑也」, 者 usage is different from the three sentences below. Here 者 and 也 comprise 者…也 「判断」usage.

Comment: I don't  know the difference.

Comment: Which means here 者 functions as a pause. It would be ok as 师，传道授业解惑者也 or 师，传道授业解惑也